# what is the best way to submit a form without variables

Tags: php, jquery, json

hello everyone i try to create a small application using jquery ( json ) and php
and at this time i want to write a best code by replacing

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        var action = $(this).attr('action');
        var name = $('.name').val();
        var email = $('.email').val();
        var city = $('.city').val();
        $.post(action, {
            name: name,
            email: email,
            city: city
        }, function (data) {
            alert(data.error);
        }, 'json');
        return false;
    });
});
```

so how can i send all this variables by another method i talk about ( name , email, city )

Comment: You can use the `serialize` method. http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Sorry i don't understand your question...

Comment: Sorry, but it is not clear for me what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like that

```
$(function(){
   $('form').submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $.post(
           $(this).attr('action'),
           $(this).serialize(),
           function(data){
               alert(data.error); 
           },
           'json'
       );
   }); 
});
```

Comment: yes but how can i receive form variables in php if i use this js method

Comment: @JanyWarner as normal `$_POST` variables. `$_POST['name']` etc

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the form using $.serialize.

```
$.post('url', $(this).serialize(), ... );
```

(Note: `this` only works in scope of the form which is true for your example)

Comment: how can i receive form variables in php if i use this js method

Comment: how can i receive form variables in php if i use this js method

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST)` and see what the data looks like. That should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Well as @D.Muller said you could use something like this:

```
var serializedData = $('form').serialize();

$.post(
    'getSerializedData.php',
    {data:serializedData},
    function(data){
    }
)
```

and then in your php script you should use unserialize like that:

```
<?php

$serializedData = $_POST['data'];
$unserializedData = array();

parse_str($unserializedData,$serializedData);

print_r($unserializedData);

?>
```

---

But still, I'm not sure if that is what you're looking for. Anyway,
Hope I helped a bit!
nLamprok

Answer (score 0):

It seems I understand why you could not get posted variables. Because, you did not **specify attribute "name"** to your input fields. Use **name** attribute instead of **class** to pass a variable name to your php script.